# Finding multiple entries in a file

Tags: batch-file

I want to include in a result file only the multiple entries that exist in another file. Each multiple entry should only be listed once in the result file. I have created a test file and a batch to achieve this, but the result file remains hopeless empty. Can anyone help me? I don't see what the problem is.Thanks in advance.

This is the input file I use, but in fact any file with multiple entries is fine:

```
Pomme
Poire
Scoubidou
Pêche
Concombre
Huile
Vinaigre
Moutarde
Noisette
Voiture
Marron
Potiron
Orange
Citron
Misaine
Noix
Bidule
Chose
Machin
Truc
Bazar
Machin
Voiture
Lampe
Potiron
Misaine
Poire
Orange
Mélange
Mazout
Cacatois
Misaine
Beaupré
Artimon
Foc
Voiture
Navette
Concombre
```

And here is the batch file:

```bash
echo off
set "oldarg="
set "dup="
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
del C:\Users\OM\Documents\Liste_triee.txt
sort C:\Users\OM\Documents\Liste_a_traiter.txt /o C:\Users\OM\Documents\Liste_triee.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type C:\Users\OM\Documents\Liste_triee.txt') do (if /i %%i==!oldarg! (if not defined dup echo(%%i >C:\Users\OM\Documents\Liste_a_afficher.txt set dup=1) else set "dup=" set oldarg=%%i)
pause
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
Concombre
Orange
Poire
Potiron
Voiture
```

Comment: Does this single line methodology work for you? ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIG:"%UserProfile%\Documents\Liste_a_traiter.txt" "%UserProfile%\Documents\Liste_a_afficher.txt" | %SystemRoot\System32\sort.exe /Unique```. You may need to switch around `Liste_a_traiter.txt` and `Liste_a_afficher.txt` according to whichever is the source list.

Comment: Or perhaps, to match lines, not substrings: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /XLIG:"%UserProfile%\Documents\Liste_a_traiter.txt" "%UserProfile%\Documents\Liste_a_afficher.txt" | %SystemRoot\System32\sort.exe /Unique```

Comment: thanks Compo for your procedure, but the output file (liste_a_afficher) remains empty.

Comment: [Edit] your question, Sorgel129, and submit the content of both `Liste_a_traiter.txt` and `Liste_a_afficher.txt`. Once we have both of them, we can all check, or fix the command to output the content you've already shown us. Without doing that, there is nothing else we can offer, especially as at least one of the command lines I've offered should work as written.